# Gnome terminal, `less` opens file at the cursor position, not at the top of terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, less

If I try to open a file with `less`, its content starts from the cursor position, not from top of the screen.

[image: screenshot].

This happens only in gnome-terminal, for example in Terminator everything is ok. How can I fix it?

Comment: Confirmed, this exists. Tends to happen mostly with short files, though , long files aren't affected.

Comment: If you hit `r` in less , it redraws screen and repositions the text. Use that as workaround for now

Comment: @Serg and OP: Can't reproduce. Whats you `less` and `gnome-terminal` version? Also is `less` the binary one or any alias or such in place?

Comment: @heemayl there's no `less` alias by default, and the version is `less 481 `, gnome-terminal `3.18.3` , Ubuntu 16.04.  Try this: open new terminal window, type in a few commands, to bring line towards half or bottom of the window, then try to open `less file.txt`, where `file.txt` is file with like 5 or 10 lines.

Comment: @Serg Still no with my 14.04's default setup. Seems like a regression.

Comment: @heemayl could be the case, gnome-terminal underwent quite  a few changes  between 14.04 and 16.04  versions. And to be perfectly frank, i don't quite like the new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by egmont, `less` should be able to position the cursor, and there is indeed a way to do so.  According to `less` man page:

> Options are also taken from the environment variable "LESS".  For
>   example, to avoid typing "less -options ..." each time less is
>   invoked, you might tell csh:
>
> setenv LESS "-options"
>
> or if you use sh:
>
> LESS="-options"; export LESS

So, in order to let `less` redraw the screen with cursor positioned up on top, do

```
echo   'LESS="-c"; export LESS' >> ~/.bashrc
```

`-c` option, which stands for "clear screen", will be appended to every `less` automatically and will even work in TTY, clearing the screen and repositioning the cursor

Answer (score 1):

`gnome-terminal` and `terminator` both rely on the `vte` widget for terminal emulation, although `terminator` uses an ancient (gtk2-based) one. More precisely, `terminator` uses `vte` version 0.28.2 (both in Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.06), whereas `gnome-terminal` uses `vte` version 0.34.9 in Ubuntu 14.04, and 0.42.5 in Ubuntu 16.04.

As with most software, newer versions should be more stable and feature rich and contain fewer bugs (although sure new bugs, regressions, changes that people don't like etc. might sneak in every now and then). `vte` did receive a massive amount of changes (fixes) in the last 3 years, including this one.

`vte` aims to use `xterm` as its reference for the emulation behavior (unless it sees a good reason to diverge, which happens very rarely). In this case we did not see a reason to diverge (and probably we had a valid bugreport about `vte` not working as expected wrt. the cursor position when switching to the alternate screen), so we fixed `vte` to behave like `xterm`.

In other words, Ubuntu 14.04's `gnome-terminal`, and both 14.04's and 16.04's `terminator` were broken, assuming that we accept that the correct behavior is defined by `xterm`. `terminator` is way behind with `vte` version and will receive this fix (along with many others) when they finally release a gtk3-based version.

I understand that you don't like the new behavior of `less` (actually I don't like it either and I prefer the way it accidentally worked with older `vte`), however, it would be an absolutely wrong approach to intentionally break `vte` to achieve the previous behavior. Instead `less` should be able to position the cursor at the top of the screen. If the current behavior really bothers you, I recommend that you file a bugreport / feature request against `less`.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. I've tested less behaviour on the tty1, and there is almost same behaviour, with exception: previous commands are not hidden.

Comment: The Linux console doesn't support the so-called "alternate screen" to which utilities such as `less`, `mc`, `vim` etc. switch to, which when you leave and go back to the "normal screen" its previous contents are restored.

Comment: `less` indeed has an option to reposition the  cursor, and it can be made to work in TTY.  See my answer.